# PATH Variable, bashrc and bash_profile messed up on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, path-variables

I can't remember which file I have changed. But I believe it was one of bashrc or bash_profile and now when I run any command with "rvm", I get "rvm command not found". I got no idea what's bashrc or bash_profile. Can someone please tell me what the content should be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the rvm path to .bashrc

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

#This loads rvm
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me out of a big trouble :)